# Css how to have transitions from :hover and normal, but change the value without transition when the page loads

Tags: css, css-transitions

Basically I have this code:

```css
#test {
    color: white;
    transition: all 1s;
    display: inline;
}

#test:hover {
    color: red;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

It works as expected. When I hover over the text it transitions into red, and then when I stop hovering over it, it turns back to white. But the problem is that since the default is black, when the page loads in the start, you see the transition from black to white. What I need is for the text to be white from the start, then have all the transitions work correctly

EDIT: Everything seems to be working fine on https://martinGITHUBER.github.io and the problem only occurs localy, so I guess ill just have to deal with Chrome being weird

Comment: If `test` is the id of the element on page load then no transition will occur. Your question implies you have some JS controlling the selectors which you should include for a complete answer.

Comment: @lawrence-witt no i don't have any js included at all

Comment: It should not transition in from black if `test` is the original id of the element - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pd8xmj3c/). Perhaps your CSS is being loaded in too late i.e. not in the `head` of the document? Can't suggest much more without a more complete example of your code.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Hmm if you look at https://martinGITHUBER.github.io you can see everythings fine........ but if I look at index.html localy then I can see the transition black to white.... weird. This will be a big problem when editing the code since it acts incorrectly locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo and managed to reproduce the problem in a limited scenario. It seems that in Chrome (maybe some other non-Windows browsers too, I'm not able to check) when you open an `index.html` file directly in the browser it will not load in the elements in the `head` in time before the first paint happens. This means the CSS is being applied to the page too late and will trigger a transition.

The solution is to use a proper development server which will give you lots of added benefits like hot reloading and, as was required in this example, a true-to-life browser environment where resources are fetched and not directly linked by the filesystem. If you're using VSCode then the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) plugin is a good tool, otherwise you can install simple Command Line tools like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) or various plugins for bundlers like webpack and rollup if your project uses those.

Comment: Ok yea thats what seems to happen. if I go to martinGITHUBER.github.io then its fine, but localy no. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

set `css` of the parent of `#test`. because HTML tags inherit CSS properties from his parents.

```css
#parent-container {
        color: white;
    }

    #test {
        color: white;
        transition: all 1s;
        display: inline;
    }

    #test:hover {
        color: red;
        transition: all 1s;
    }
```

```html
<div id='parent-container'>
    <span id='test'>hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS properties are not inherited if the selector defines its own property of the same type. Set the `color` of `#test` to green in your example and it will be green, not white.

Comment: as per the question, on page reload text changes from black to white. because the parent has text color black, I just suggested the tweak to make the parent text white. so it will not show the transition from black to white when the page reloaded.

Comment: Hm this doesn't seem to work, but @lawrence-witt said the right thing. This problem only occurs locally, not on https://martinGITHUBER.github.io

Comment: you just test what I have given, in your local and let me know. local having problem because of some rendering and rapid file serving.